# Make sure I am getting one entry using Randomness

Tags: java, random, string-utils

I am trying to generate random columns with the use of below method and after generating columns, I am using those columns in my `SELECT sql`.

```
final String columnsList = getColumns(table.getColumns());
final String selectSql = "SELECT ID, CREATION_DATE, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, " + columnsList + "  from " + table.getTableName() + " where id = ?";

/**
 * A simple method to get the column names in the order in which it was
 * inserted
 * 
 * @param columns
 * @return
 */
private String getColumns(final List<String> columns) {
    List<String> copy = new ArrayList<String>(columns);
    Collections.shuffle(copy);

    int rNumber = random.nextInt(columns.size());

    List<String> subList = copy.subList(0, rNumber);
    Collections.sort(subList, new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return columns.indexOf(o1) < columns.indexOf(o2) ? -1 : 1;
        }
    });
    return StringUtils.join(subList, ",");
}
```

**Problem Statement:-**

Sometimes I have seen is `columnsList` value is empty and if it is empty then `selectSql` will not work as there will be extra `,` before `from keyword`. How can I make sure `getColumns` should return atleast one entry everytime.

I believe `nextInt` will generate random number between `0 (inclusively) and n (exclusively)`. So it might be possible that it will pick 0 sometimes, Any way to generate random number between `1(inclusively) and n (exclusively)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is:

```
return subList.isEmpty() ? "1" : StringUtils.join(subList, ",");
```

But I think better is to modify `selectSql` to

```
final String selectSql = "SELECT ID, CREATION_DATE, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE " + columnsList + "  from " + table.getTableName() + " where id = ?";
```

And then

```
return subList.isEmpty() ? "" : ","+StringUtils.join(subList, ",");
```

If you want at leas one value from random you can also use this:

```
int rNumber = 1+random.nextInt(columns.size()-1);
```

Comment: Thanks valodzka. After editing like this, I am getting this exception sometimes `java.sql.SQLException: Column '' not found in results.` Do you know why it is happening?

Comment: What other code should I provide here? I tried your other way as well which is giving me some other exception.

Comment: What kind of error you get when using "int rNumber = 1+random.nextInt(columns.size()-1);"?